# Admob banner and interstitial ads not loading on launcher activity

Tags: android, admob

The first time when I load my app the banner ad and the full screen interstitial ad does not load. Every other time when i hit that (or any other) Activity the ads load fine. This leads me to believe that its not a fill issue. Also i am not using any mediation, just the standard Admob network.

Below is the code i use to load the banner ad

```
AdView bannerAdView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    if (Settings.SHOW_ADS) {
        AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        bannerAdView.loadAd(adRequestBanner);
    }
```

Log cat reports back the following error

```
10-11 21:33:51.749  19409-19439/ W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
10-11 21:33:51.839  19409-19409/ W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
10-11 21:33:47.039  19409-19409/ E/Ads﹕ JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
```

Is there anything i can do to make the ad load close to 100% of the time, especially the full screen ad?

Comment: Have you added permission in manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23153451/1777090) helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not, i updated the question with more detailed logs..

Comment: Try loading test ads first. Click here to see how to load test ad https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#test_ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has disappeared when upgrading to the latest google play services lib in my Gradle file.

At the time of writing this, the latest version is `6.1.71` and the dependancy looks like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

Answer (score 6):

Also Your package might be blocked by Google AdMob. 
If you received a email like this:

> Hello,
>
> This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not
>   currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a
>   result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.
>
> Issue ID#: 33943***
>
> Ad serving has been disabled to: **APPNAME**
>   (com.example.pack)
>
> Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your
>   account for compliance.
>
> Current account status: Active
>
> Violation explanation
>
> GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or
>   promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube,
>   or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to
>   circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products,
>   such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.
>
> If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please
>   contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play
>   reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.
>
> Action required: Check account for compliance
>
> While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob
>   account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review
>   the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance
>   with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the
>   likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note
>   that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we
>   continue to see violations occurring.
>
> Appeals
>
> If you wish to appeal this disabling then you can do so by using our
>   appeal form.
>
> Thank you for your cooperation.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Google AdMob Team

So now you need to change your package of your app. on eclipse it is  `package="com.example"` in AndroidManifest.xml file

or

on AndroidStudio `applicationId "com.example"` in build.gradle file

Comment: Im facing same issue against one of app, how can we fix it without package change? changing package mean we must upload new app

Comment: Was faced the same issue and after changing the package name temporary for testing, it was working fine.

@ Aqib Mumtaz. You have to contact to google help support team.

Comment: @AqibMumtaz you can't. Google doesn't support developers after ban(
in 99% cases). You just need to create a new dev account with another person's passport, and credit card, and another comp IP and MAC address, and then new app with another package name

Comment: Fortunately In my case, I contacted with AdMob team and requested them to fix issue for me after showing evidences that my app isn't going against AdMob policy guidelines and they fixed it :))

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that your Activity loads faster than the Ad. So the Ad isn't ready by the time your activity loads and so the ad doesn't show. Here is a screenshot of my LogCat showing you the different steps the Ad takes to get ready. [image]

Also, if the Ad is showing and another Activity (Activity B) is called, then Activity B will override the Ad. You can see that the Ad is still on the stack by pushing the back button on your phone/emulator. Pushing that button should return u back to the Ad.

Comment: thanks for the effort, ill try coming up with a solution and post it up soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check paddingLeft, paddingRight in main layout if present try to remove them. Have similar problem that fixed with padding remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test ads using adMobs, you need to use the test ad id which is : **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111**.

If you are displaying a test ad and using your private Ad id, it won't work.