# Google AdMob loading ads

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

currently I am trying to load ads into my application. I have followed the guide and this is what i've gotten:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:isGame="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

   ...

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>
```

I've added the `AdView` like so:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner_id"
    />
```

And finally the the code to load the ad:

```
adView = (AdView) m.findViewById(R.id.ad_banner);
AdRequest req = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my device id").build();
adView.loadAd(req);
```

Now the code seems to be alright but when I run it I get the following logcat output:

```
E/GmsClient﹕ unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START

W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(328)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

And then nothing displays where the ad should be. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and why the previous errors are coming up? Thanks.

EDIT: I tried it on a different device (Nexus 4 running 5.1) and the ads seemed to work. But it they don't on my Nexus 5 running 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to by my phones fault. An application was secretly blocking the google play service ad services. I just had to disable this and it was fine, so nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Im facing the exact same problem, would you you please elaborate how did you fix it ?

Comment: I have rooted my phone and I have a application called lucky patcher installed. It allows you to block Google ads. I had that option selected though I didn't know it

Comment: Thanks for your replay. btw I fixed my similar problem with different method, I had custom ROM and it had pre ad blocker integrated. Obviously my phone is rooted as well so go to file manager then go to root folder (device folder) then go to /etc/ folder there I found a file named Hosts, this file has all the URLs of ads agencies and those URLs were looped back with 127.0.0.1 IP. Simply delete that file and restarted my phone. Now my ads work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have latest version of Google Play Services library.

Check this similar question [Admob banner and interstitial ads not loading on launcher activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313488/admob-banner-and-interstitial-ads-not-loading-on-launcher-activity)

Comment: I am using google play services 7.0.0. I've got the following under my dependencies: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'`