# Ads are not showing up in my app

Tags: admob

I have followed below link to integrate admob ads in my app

http://www.coderefer.com/admob-android-ads-integration/

This is my logcat error

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRzt6.png)

Comment: Ads are showing up but only test ad is showing up.what to do?

Answer (score -1):

1. First all read console it says:
   **there was a problem getting an ad response. errorcode 0**
2. Than you need to search in your preferred search engine for that error:
3. Than you will see that this question has been asked before in here [Admob banner and interstitial ads not loading on launcher activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313488/admob-banner-and-interstitial-ads-not-loading-on-launcher-activity)

Comment: when i open my admob account it shows to link to firebase.Will that help

Comment: Ads are showing up but only test ad is showing up.what to do?

Comment: You need to request real add signatures, for example Adsense gives test server and real but if you use real server and accidentally click on it it will count false positive and you maybe-will be banned so you need to find real ad server or switch between, depend on provider.

Comment: Do you know how to request real ad signatures in admob.If so help me

Comment: Follow this steps read carefully https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start all described in here