# Admob sdk error code:0

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add admob ads in my app.I followed Google tutorial but it didn't work.This is my code:

In `OnCreate()` method:

```
   AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   adView.loadAd(request);
```

Main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.impact.ribony">



    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor  ="#0B0B16"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true" />"

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxx.xxxx"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.0.7" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name=".Trackers"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/xxxx_top_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
                    <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".MainActivity" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Log file:

```
11-10 12:00:22.592: W/Ads(1950): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-10 12:00:22.592: D/dalvikvm(1950): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1321K, 15% free 8406K/9788K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
11-10 12:00:22.600: W/Ads(1950): Failed to load ad: 0
```

What can be cause this ? What is the problem ? I didn't understand this error.

Comment: create new admob id and use it there is np error about tha coading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23153451/624069

Comment: But I tried with test ads id(http://prntscr.com/54x706)  result is same.

Comment: Also I created new admob id now.Getting still same error.

Comment: Is there any more log before or after what you posted?

Comment: @William Here you can see:http://pastebin.com/CtGqVK64

Comment: Is this on a device on on an emulator? You won't get real ads on an emulator, you need to configure your AdRequest to return for a test device.

Comment: This is an emulator.Now test ads are showing sometimes and not showing sometimes.I didn't understand this problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case the code was correct, google-ply-services was updated!

But I was having a new admob account with new banner & interstitial id's !

It took 2 days & the problem was automatically solved & It start displaying ads...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the packages in the SDK manager. Open the SDK manager, then check all the packages under EXTRA that have an update available.

After updating the packages, add the following dependency in your build.gradle(app).

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```